# Phonegap - Back button reloading complete page

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, cordova, back

I have a list of 100 items of which first 20 items are displayed, these 20 items are fetched from server through ajax call.
There is a load more button which will fetch the next 20 items and so on.
Now when i goto next screen for say 70th item which has details of the list item and then again go back using
data-rel = "back" the list will again fetch server data from 1-20 only.

Is there any thing in phonegap which will store all the fetched data and work exactly the same way as the browser back button?

Comment: you can't work with multiple html pages in phonegap, you need to stay on one page and alter it contents. you can achieve described results with mobile frameworks like jQuery Mobile tough.

Comment: Why don't you use local storage to hold the current offset in your data (70) and load items through ajax and passing this offset to the ajax post/get whatever call you do? For multiple steps check out the window.history documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use local storage to hold the current offset in your data (70) and load items through ajax and passing this offset to the ajax post/get whatever call you do? For multiple steps check out the window.history documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: yes that is one option, but isnt there anything that will store the complete instance of that page? because the user has already waited and made a server call to get those things, i know i can store everything on a local copy of database. but if there is anything it would be good

Answer (score 0):

Did you try JQM?

In JQM, you can just use data-dom-cach="true" for caching a page.

Like:`<div data-role="page" data-dom-cache="true">`

But don't forget release the page what you cached!

[JQM data-dom-cache Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/pages/)